# What is A* in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am very very new to Scala. I am reading a book called functional programming in scala by Paul Chiusano and Rúnar Bjarnason. So far I am finding it interesting.

I see the following

```
def apply[A] (as:A*) : List[A] =
  if(as.isEmpty) Nil
  else Cons(as.head,apply(as.tail: _*))
```

I would like to know how to read (as:A*), can anybody explain me what it is or point me to some online docs to understand this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: There is a varvargs entry in the [Functions page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/477/functions#t=201608041631299474664) of SO's Documentation (beta) project.

Answer (score 5):

It's a *varargs*, or variable number of arguments (0 or more). E.g.

```
def takesNStrings(strings: String*) {
    // you can now iterate through the zero or more strings...
}
```

Some [examples here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-varargs-syntax-function-examples)

Answer (score 1):

It's varargs.

```
def f[A](xs: A*) = xs.foreach(println)
```

You can call this function in a couple of ways.

With no parameters:

```
f()
```

Passing multiple parameters (any number of parameters can be used):

```
f(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Passing a sequence:

```
val a = Seq(1,2,3,4) // other collections work as well
f(a: _*)
```

The type of `xs` inside of `f` is a `Seq[A]`.